# How to Create Tree in Chameleon Template Using TAL and Nested Set List (Modified Preorder Tree Traversal)

Tags: python, tree, mptt, chameleon

I'm using the nested set hierarchy, or modified preorder tree traversal (MPTT) algorithm, as described [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), and I'm having a difficult time understanding how to translate the depth and category name into a Chameleon template to display a nested tree using `<ul>` and `<li>`.

I have a `dict` that has both depth and category name information for all the categories that looks like:

```
[{'depth': 1L, 'name': 'CategoryA'}, {'depth': 2L, 'name': 'CategoryB', ...]
```

Adapting this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310649/getting-a-modified-preorder-tree-traversal-model-nested-set-into-a-ul), the way to print this information in Python is:

```
category_ul = ""
current_depth = -1 
category_list.pop(0)

while category_list:
    current_node = category_list.pop(0)

    category_name = current_node['name'] 
    category_depth = current_node['depth'] 

    if category_depth > current_depth:
        category_ul += "<ul>\n"

    if category_depth < current_depth:
        category_ul += "</ul>\n" * (current_depth - category_depth)

    category_ul += "<li>%s</li>\n" % str(category_name)

    current_depth = category_depth

    if not category_list:
        category_ul += "</ul>\n" * (current_depth + 1)
```

What I'd like to do is translate this Python code to something that can be used in a Chameleon template using `tal`.

The closest answer I have seen is [Rendering nested elements with an arbitrary depth using Chameleon ZPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685684/rendering-nested-elements-with-an-arbitrary-depth-using-chameleon-zpt), but it requires children nodes for each node, which doesn't seem to be the right solution.

So, my question is:  How can I implement the Python code above in a Chameleon template?  I'd really appreciate any help I can get.  So far, I have tried:

```
<tal:block tal:define="current_depth -1">
  <tal:block tal:repeat="category categories_list">
    <ul tal:condition="python:category['depth'] > current_depth">${category['name']}</ul>
    <tal:block tal:define:"current_depth category['depth']"></tal:block>
    <span>current_depth: ${current_depth}</span>
  </tal:block>
</tal:block>
```

But, `current_depth` is always defined as -1.  If it isn't obvious from the template code above, I'm pretty new to it, so any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.